# Can't find fan speed setting on Supermicro X9DRW

Tags: bios, supermicro, hardware, physical-environment

I have one Supermicro server with a X9DRW board, BIOS v1.0a, that does not seem to have any way of controlling fan speed. I've looked through the entire BIOS, including the usual location of Advanced->Hardware Health->Fan Speed Control.

The reason why I am attempting to change the setting is that our other servers with the same motherboard and BIOS revision are running their fans between 5-6k RPM, but this one is reporting 12-13k RPM. Chassis temperature is the same around 40C.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you call support for Supermicro gear?

Answer (score 2):

On X9DRW motherboard you could tune fan speed with IPMI/BMC: e.g. using Supermicro IPMIView app, going to "IPMI device" tab, "Fan Speed Mode" section.

[image]

By default, "Standard" mode is selected (gives about 5000 rpm in my case). "Full" (about 12000 rpm) seems is what you're looking for.

Comment: How do you get more granular control of each individual fan? IPMIView seems to just give a few preset options.